# Saving data to Kusto DB

Tags: azure-data-explorer

i am having issue while Saving data to Kusto Db from c# code. i am running the following code and i am getting error in ExecuteControlCommand. Can any one help on this issue. i tried all the options but still no luck

```
public static void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            var clusterName = "ABC";
            var db = "Kusto";
            var table = "Log";
            var mappingName = "KustoJsonMapping";

            // Set up table
            var kcsbEngine =
                new KustoConnectionStringBuilder($"https://KustoDB.kusto.windows.net");

            using (var kustoAdminClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kcsbEngine))
            {
                var columns = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("logId", "System.String"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("logDtm", "System.DateTime"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("userName", "System.String"),
        };

                var command = CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableCreateCommand(table, columns);
                kustoAdminClient.ExecuteControlCommand(databaseName: db, command: command);

                // Set up mapping
                var columnMappings = new List<JsonColumnMapping>();
                columnMappings.Add(new JsonColumnMapping()
                { ColumnName = "logId", JsonPath = "$.Id" });
                columnMappings.Add(new JsonColumnMapping()
                { ColumnName = "logDtm", JsonPath = "$.Timestamp" });
                columnMappings.Add(new JsonColumnMapping()
                { ColumnName = "userName", JsonPath = "$.Message" });

                command = CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableJsonMappingCreateCommand(
                                                    table, mappingName, columnMappings);
                kustoAdminClient.ExecuteControlCommand(databaseName: db, command: command);
            }

            }
        }
```

Comment: you mentioned you're getting an error - could you please share the content of that error?

Comment: Kusto.Data: Unauthorized (): Authorization has been denied for this request..  i am not getting option to add .WithAadUserPromptAuthentication();  var kcsbEngine =
                new KustoConnectionStringBuilder($"https://KustoDB.kusto.windows.net");

Comment: I am assuming you are using the .Net Standard package? if so, it does not provide the prompt option indeed.

Can you try switching over to the .net framework package?

If you prefer the .net standard version, you can use app authentication as @YoniL provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the application have the required permissions to the table? The error message from your comment suggest it does not.

You can grant it permissions using control commands mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/security-roles#managing-table-security-roles).

Or, using [Kusto.Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer#managing-authorized-principals), if you have it installed.

The required permission is `TableIngestor` (explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-permissions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/access-control/role-based-authorization))

Comment: After i have made the chages i am getting following error   Kusto.Data: Unauthorized (): Authorization has been denied for this request.. This normally represents a permanent error, and retrying is unlikely to help.
[1/16/2019 10:07:13 PM] Please provide the following information when contacting the Kusto team @ https://aka.ms/kustosupport :

Answer (score 0):

After giving your application permission, you also need to present credentials to the cluster.